# IDispatchMessageInspector altered xml

Tags: xml, wcf

Im using WCF with a universal contract. Logging of incoming and outgoing messages is done via IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest and IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply

Recently I discovered that the Message content is not the same as my input.

Data I produced for the reply:

```
<OTA_PingRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <Success />
  <EchoData>Just some text24</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
```

Sending is done with a normal reader. elMessageResult is the above xml.

```
private Message CreateResponse(MessageVersion ver, XElement elMessageResult)
{
    Message response = Message.CreateMessage(ver, "ProcessMessageResponse", elMessageResult.CreateReader());
    return response;
}
```

BeforeSendReply copies the message and reads the xml

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    Message replyCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();

    XDocument doc;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        replyCopy.WriteMessage(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        doc = XDocument.Load(ms);
    }

    if (SaveLog != null)
    {
        LogSaveFileEventArgs logEventArgs = new LogSaveFileEventArgs(doc, true);
        SaveLog(this, logEventArgs);
    }

    reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
}
```

XDocument doc from BeforeSendReply contains altered xml. The Success element is `<Success></Success>` instead of `<Success />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">ProcessMessageResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:4D549F7F6D8D65FE891401181704779</a:RelatesTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <OTA_PingRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <Success></Success>
      <EchoData>Just some text24</EchoData>
    </OTA_PingRS>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The strange thing is that on client side the original xml with correct Success element is received. Tested that using SoapUI.

This might be a minor issue since the xml is still valid but who knows what else will be altered. I rely on proper logging for investigations in case of errors.

I already played around with XmlWriterSettings without success.
Any ideas?

Edit:

replyCopy.ToString() already contains the wrong formated xml.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Success />` tag is getting changed when you create the buffered copy of the message.

```
reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
```

If you wanted to avoid that, you would need to do something like below where you write the message to the `XmlWriter`, load your `XDocument` save you xml or whatever, then create a new message to pass on your reply. I do something similar to this in one of my services.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
    m.WriteMessage(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.Load(ms);

    //savelog

    ms.Position = 0;

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings //may not be needed
    {
        IgnoreWhitespace = true
    };

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);
    var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, m.Version);
    newMessage.Headers.Clear();
    newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(m.Headers);
}
```

Comment: CreateBufferedCopy seems to do the modifications. Reason unknown. Your solution with XmlDocument and PreserveWhitespaces works but does not do significant different when mine from the question. You still get altered xml.
Rewriting the response from the xml (instead of reply = buffer.CreateMessage()) is not necessary here as the response in the client is correct.